# Information about which devices are connected to the Pi-3 Access Point

Tags: pi-3, wireless, dhcp

**Device**: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

**Firmware**: `hostapd` and `dnsmasq` for Wireless Access Point Creation using `systemd` service.

I have successfully created a Wireless Access Point on the Pi and can easily connect my Android Phone and a couple of [Particle Photons](https://www.particle.io/products/hardware/photon-wifi-dev-kit). Through the firmware on the Photons I can view what their IP addresses are. However this is the client perspective. What about the Raspberry Pi as a DHCP'ish Server. Does it have a log of all the Devices it gave the IP addresses to? for example, A log file where the **MAC Addresses** / **IP addresses** of the connected devices?

I tried following [This Unix/Linux SE query](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40087/is-there-a-way-to-list-the-connected-devices-on-my-wifi-access-point#40123) but it actually doesn't give me any information at all.

Thanks.